# How to make a fix td width in bootstrap with scroll in overflow-x

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi everyone please help me how to make a table whose `<td>` is fixed and also could have a scroll when overflow-x.

I tried using `<td class="col-md-X">` but it doesn't allows scroll it just became a responsive table after I added this code. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Add your code or make a JSFiddle or a Plunker please.